# How to create PolyLine in MapView IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have create a project. I want to draw a PolyLine in MapView by google direction URL. I tried to many tutorials and links but don't get any successfully draw PolyLine. Please suggest any tutorial, How to draw PolyLine. Please help. Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

```
GMSPolyline *poly = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
poly.strokeColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
poly.tappable = TRUE;
poly.map = self.googleMapView;
```

And for porject with google Map see this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/

Comment: Please suggest to How to call url and how to decrypted and after draw line

Comment: @DivankKumawat go to google website i have given you a url, lots of example is there

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer this straight forward way IF YOU ARE USING GOOGLE MAPS.

```
GMSPolyline *polyPath = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:[GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:encodedPath]];
```

Following is a complete code snippet.

```
-(void)drawPathFrom:(CLLocation*)source toDestination:(CLLocation*)destination{

NSString *baseUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=true", source.coordinate.latitude,  source.coordinate.longitude, destination.coordinate.latitude,  destination.coordinate.longitude];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[baseUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog(@"Url: %@", url);
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if(!connectionError){
        NSDictionary *result        = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSArray *routes             = [result objectForKey:@"routes"];
        NSDictionary *firstRoute    = [routes objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *encodedPath       = [firstRoute[@"overview_polyline"] objectForKey:@"points"];

        GMSPolyline *polyPath       = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:[GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:encodedPath]];
        polyPath.strokeColor        = [UIColor redColor];
        polyPath.strokeWidth        = 3.5f;
        polyPath.map                = _mapView;
    }
}];}
```

Comment: I'd suggest replacing the deprecated `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:...]` with `[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:...]`

Comment: @sandy How to add lat long in source?

Comment: I added like this :  NSString *baseUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=true", 24.4764,  74.8624, 24.4748,  75.1404];
 am i right sandy?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: 
http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-draw-an-mkpolyline-on-a-map-view/

OR

```
- (void) drawRoute:(NSArray *) path {
    NSInteger numberOfSteps = path.count;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[numberOfSteps];
    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < numberOfSteps; index++) {
        CLLocation *location = [path objectAtIndex:index];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
        coordinates[index] = coordinate;
    }
    MKPolyline *polyLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:numberOfSteps];
    [map addOverlay:polyLine];
}
```